# What is the best way to include JavaScript file using script tag?

Tags: javascript

I generally include JavaScript files using the script tag as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile.js"></script>
```

I have seen some people using the language attribute as well.

Now-a-days I find many people omitting the type attribute. I have started to get a feeling that if JavaScript is the default scripting language then even I should omit the type attribute. Would it be good to omit the type attribute? Would it cause any problems?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Take a look at this as a reference (Book of Speed): http://www.bookofspeed.com/chapter3.html

Essentially the best way is to combine all your javascript into one file called something like all.min.js that is also minimized.

Typically in HTML5 you would do something like:

```
<script src="js/all.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, [you **DO NOT** need the type attribute in HTML5, but you do in other versions of HTML and XHTML](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-script-element.html). The spec clarifies that if the content is other than "text/javascript" then you need to specify the type attribute, in HTML5.

Some things to remember:

- Always [include it before the closing  tag](http://labjs.com/);
- You should [load your scripts in a non-blocking pattern](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2008/07/22/non-blocking-scripts/).

Note:

If you are going to specify another type other than `text/javascript` you would use one of the following:

- "application/ecmascript"
- "application/javascript"
- "application/x-ecmascript"
- "application/x-javascript"
- "text/ecmascript" "text/javascript"
- "text/javascript1.0"
- "text/javascript1.1"
- "text/javascript1.2"
- "text/javascript1.3"
- "text/javascript1.4"
- "text/javascript1.5"
- "text/jscript"
- "text/livescript"
- "text/x-ecmascript"
- "text/x-javascript"
- "text/javascript;e4x=1"

The above list is from: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-script-element.html#scriptingLanguages

Remember that you would not use the language attribute, only the type attribute.

Comment: And what about the language attribute. Is it good to specify it or omit it?

Comment: The language attribute is not supported in HTML5, instead they have merged it with the type attribute. Again, if it is something other than "text/javascript" then you would specify it using the type attribute and one of the following from this page:http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-script-element.html

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect my comment above.

Comment: Does setting something like `text/javascript1.3` have any actual effect, different than omitting it?